# Domino lotus notes 8.5.3 Form does not load all the controls?

Tags: forms, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

I need to show a form to the user from Lotus notes customization extension file (Forms85.nsf). For that I have created a form in Customization file i.e. in Forms85_x.nsf Extension file. The form is properly loaded with all the controls (buttons ,textboxes ,comboboxes) while I’m previewing in Domino server but, whenever I’m trying to access the form from users browser it doesn’t show the controls like button. But the controls in the forms are loading properly while I’m having the form in users own mail file i.e. someone.nsf.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "buttons", are you talking about action buttons in the action menu, or buttons on the form?
The mail template is web-enabled, but you may done something on your form that won't work on the web.
What code do you have behind your buttons? Are you using Lotuscript of Formula?

Also, to be picky (but we are all developers, and it is a requirement to be precise for us), you probably mean that you previw it in Notes (using the Notes client), not Domino. Domino is the server, and the only way to view an appliaction on teh Domino server is by using a browser.

You can do really cool things in Domino web applications, with justa  little bit of CSS and Javascript. I frequently use jQuery to create more advance web application, calling Lotusscript agents through Ajax to read/write/update documents in the database. Perhaps you can use that technique?

Answer (score 0):

Customizing iNotes does not work like that. You found the right place to add your customization code, but unfortunately not the right way to do it. The forms in forms85_x.nsf are not supposed to be used as "normal" forms. You put html and javascript in there as plain text (no passthrough html).

Action buttons can be added by using special javascript commands, not by adding buttons in the form. Start reading [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp#mobileCategoryList) about how to do this.

Just forget about everything you know about web-development in domino (classic or xpages) and learn how to do "iNotes" as the only thing in common are the "languages" html and javascript and css